# addClass() not working as expected in if clause in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm pretty new to jQuery and I have the following problem. So, I want jQuery to listen when the user clicks on the `li` element and if the element already has class of `active` it should return from the function. If an element doesn't have a class of `active` then, it should add a class to it. So, what I want is to add class when the element is clicked but only one element at the time can have the class of `active`. But right now, my code is adding `active` class to every element I click. Down below is the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <h3>Lists</h3>
            <hr class="divider">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span> Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span> Travel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> School</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

<script>
    (function () {

        $('.nav').children('li').on('click', function () {
            $this = $(this);

            if ( $this.hasClass('active') ) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                $this.addClass('active');
            }

        });

    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Try t=$(this); t.hasClass('active') and t.addClass('active')

Comment: Why the assignment to `$this` instead of just directly working with `$(this)`?

Comment: Also, have you tried something like: `!$(this).hasClass("active") ? $(this).addClass("active") : return 0;`

Comment: and how do you plan to use returned value?

Comment: The return statement is just nonsense, and addClass only adds the class if it's not present, so you can replace all your code with `$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')`!

Comment: @adeneo Never knew that about addClass.  I tested that to be true, but is there any documentation of this fact?  The JQuery documentation makes no mention of this (though I suppose it might be implied).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    $(function(){
        $('.nav li').click(function () {
             $('.nav li').removeClass("active");    
             $(this).addClass("active");    
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do somethink like this for example:

```
(function () {
     $('.nav').on('click', 'li', function () {
         $(this).toggleClass('active')
             .siblings('li').removeClass('active');
     });

 })();
```

`this` inside the event handler refers only to the DOM element on which event was triggered (to li that was clicked in our case). If you log `this` inside your callback function you'll see that it refers only to the one li element (which is clicked):

```
 (function () {
        $('.nav').children('li').on('click', function () {
            console.log(this); //logs <li class="active"> </li>
            //other code
    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this -

```
$('.nav').children('li').on('click', function () {
   $('.nav').children('li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically we add class and remove class from all siblings.

```
(function () 
{
    $('.nav').on('click', 'li', function() 
    {
        $(this).addClass('active')
               .siblings('li')
               .removeClass('active');
    });
})();
```